# Master Config on Mac with AMPPS

Tags: focus-lab-master-config

I installed EE 2.11.1 on Mac with AMPPS, and am trying to set up the Master Config from FocusLabs. Following the directions from [here](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) everything works fine until I copy/paste the contents of system/expressionengine/config/database.php into my corresponding database.php file. When I do that, I get the white screen of death on both the front end and the control panel.

A few things I've tried:

- Turning on debug isn't giving me any info...still just the white screen.
- I added an `exit('here');` to the top of the config.local.php file...it is pulling in the file.
- I uploaded to the "dev" and "production" servers and it worked fine, so seems to just be isolated to my local environment.
- The database connection is working fine since I was using the same credentials when I installed EE, but before attempting to set up Master Config.

Any suggestions for further troubleshooting?

Comment: Regarding the white screen of death, have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death/18208549#18208549

Comment: I hadn't seen that post...that was helpful. Entering that into my /system/expressionengine/config/database.php file, I get the following error both on the front end, and on the control panel page:

`E_ERROR Error in file »mysql_driver.php« at line 73: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()`

Seems odd since running EE on my local machine works just fine, and I would think that uses the function mysql_connect(). But when using Master Config it doesn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: Glad you could diagnose the error. Sounds like this is an issue with AMPPS and your local server configuration. The first thing I'd check is if the PHP MySQL extension is enabled in AMPPS PHP settings and then restart apache. I use MAMP and am not familiar with the AMPPS interface. Then I'd suggest doing a web search for "AMPPS undefined function mysql_connect()" if that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: It was indeed AMPPS-related...thanks for the push in the right direction!

Comment: In case anybody comes across this same issue, I found the solution [here](http://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?tid=5404&tpg=all&title=Can%27t_access_AMPPS_Home) on the AMPPS forum.

Comment: Cool! I'd suggest posting your last comment as the answer and then accepting your answer to close out the question. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mjr gave me a nudge in the right direction in the comments above. In case anybody comes across this same issue, I found the solution [here](http://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?tid=5404&tpg=all&title=Can%27t_access_AMPPS_Home) on the AMPPS forum.